# What is a configuration file

Tags: configuration

What is configuration file? What does it contain?

How it is different from a plain ASCII data file?

A silly extra question: What is meta data?

Comment: Well, "a file used for configuration". Note how this is a vague term - XML, INI, some other random (and non-human readable!) format are all perfectly acceptable under this definition.

Comment: @pst I think that a configuration file contains the dynamic data which can be modified by the user during the run. And a data file(can be in any format) contains the static data used by the program. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

1. A configuration file is a file that contains configuration data.

   It could be any kind of file: XML, .properties, text, INI, etc...
2. A configuration file generally contains info about how a program works or operates.

   A data file generally provides data to a program.

   Both files may or may not be ASCII files.
3. Metadata is data about data.

   If your program displays data about houses, an example of metadata might be whether or not to display addresses.

   Such data does not describe a house; it is data about how to display house data (ie data about data).

Answer (score 0):

refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file for all detail info about Configuration file....

and about meta data http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_data

Comment: I think the OP's goal in asking this question was to avoid reading ;)

Comment: wiki gives the images for configuration file... so no need for reading ;)